# Airflow: Getting ERROR when trying to list DAGs by status "ON/OFF" in Cloud Shell

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs, google-cloud-composer, google-cloud-shell

I am using Cloud Shell to list the DAGs where the status is "ON" or "OFF" - and I am using the following command:

```
gloud composer environments storage dags list --environment=ENVIRONMENT --location=LOCATION --status=ON
```

However, when I try to execute the command above to list the DAGs that are "ON", I get this error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.composer.environments.storage.dags.list) unrecognized arguments: --status=ON
```

I can clearly see that the issue is regarding the `--status=ON` - therefore, what do I need to do in order to fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`--status` is not a valid argument for the [`airflow dags list`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/cli-and-env-variables-ref.html#list_repeat2) CLI command.

If you are trying to retrieve DAGs that are not paused, you can output the results from `airflow dags list` to a JSON object (i.e. `airflow dags list --output json`) and iterate over that array to print what DAGs are currently unpaused (i.e. paused=False).

Comment: Thanks for that. So, what would I iterate over that array and use the ```paused=False``` argument? I'm new to this, so apologies if that is a dumb question.